# Qt creator -fno-elide-constructors not working

Tags: c++, qt

I used `QMAKE_CXXFLAGS += -fno-elide-constructors` in the *.pro* and I cant get the output I need.
I'm using Qt 5.9.8 MinGW 32bit on windows 10

It's like qmake is ignoring my flag.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

using std::cout;using std::endl;using std::cin;
class C {
public:
C(){cout<<"C0";}
C(const C&){cout<<"Cc";cout<<endl;}
};
C fun(C c=C()) { C X=c;return X;}
int main()
{
      cout<<"1"<<endl;
  C c;
  cout<<endl;
  cout<<"2"<<endl;
  fun(c);
  cout<<endl;
  cout<<"3"<<endl;
  C y=fun();
  cout<<endl;
  cout<<"4"<<endl;
  fun(fun());
  cout<<endl;
  cout<<"5"<<endl;
  fun();
  cout<<endl;
}
```

This is the expected output:

1
C0

2
Cc
Cc
Cc

3
C0Cc
Cc
Cc
Cc

4
C0Cc
Cc
Cc
Cc
Cc
Cc

5
C0Cc
Cc
Cc

This is what I get:

1
C0

2
Cc
Cc

3
C0Cc

4
C0Cc
Cc

5
C0Cc

SOLUTION:

Build -> Clean Project
And now your .pro file is updated with the new flag

Comment: Which C++ version are you using?

Comment: To me it looks like the compiler has optimized away `C X=c;`, but it doesn't elide copies as `return X;` invokes the copy constructor.

Comment: @RinatVeliakhmedov was set to c++11 and I tried without

Comment: @Mestkon yes but it should be doing that with the fno-elide-constructors

Comment: @Archetipo Yes, so to me it looks like the flag is working as intended and your expected output is wrong as the flag doesn't prevent optimizing away variables. Only temporary variables passed to a copy constructor. `C X=c;` is not a temporary variable in this case.

Comment: @Mestkon I used this online compiler with the same flag setted (right corner) and I got the same result as in my book but on my Qt are still wrong

Comment: Online Compiler link [link](https://www.onlinegdb.com/online_c++_compiler)

Comment: @Archetipo Hmm, looks like you are correct. Might be a MinGW issue then. Have you tried invoking MinGW directly (not via qmake) with the same flag and checked the output?

Comment: @Mestkon Actually I have not. But 1st I will learn how to do it :) and I will try on linux too with g++ later

Comment: Have you checked the compile output to see if the flag is actually passed to the compiler?

Comment: @hyde how can i check that? I think it's not on

Comment: Today something crazy happened... I just typed everything in the same way but with the flag at the end of my .pro file and it worked!

Comment: The solution is to go on Build -> Clean Project and the new flag is used by the compiler...

Answer (score 0):

Build -> Clean Project And now your .pro file is updated with the new flag